# Can I send exoplayer buffered data to other activity exoplayer

Tags: android, video-streaming, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I have a exoplayer my first activity and when I click full screen button, I open a new VideoActivity full screen. I just only send my current position and start VideoActivity that position.

```
  TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);
  SimpleExoPlayer player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context, trackSelector);

  playerView.setPlayer(player);
  player.prepare(contentMediaSource);
  player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
  player.seekTo(positionFromFirstActivity);
```

But the problem is when open new activity and start exoplayer from current position. Exoplayer start the buffering once again.

Is there any way to carry the buffering data to SecondActivity.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: No I still pass my current position .s

Answer (score 1):

This might be too late to answer this, but this might help other people.

If you wanna implement the fullscreen functionality for the exoplayer, don't do it through a separate activity, you just need to open a dialog with hieght and width mathcing the entire screen and just need to add the playerview that you were using for the 'none-fullscreen' exoplyer.

```
mFullScreenButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if (!mExoPlayerFullscreen) {
            ((Activity) mContext).setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
            openFullscreenDialog();
        } else {
            ((Activity) mContext).setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
            closeFullscreenDialog();
        }
    });
```

here we're initializing the onClick for the fullscreen button

```
private void openFullscreenDialog() {
    ((ViewGroup) playerView.getParent()).removeView(playerView);
    mFullScreenDialog.addContentView(playerView, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    mFullScreenIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_exit_fullscreen);
    mExoPlayerFullscreen = true;
    mFullScreenDialog.show();
}
```

above is the method which is called when the fullscreen button is called for matching the screen. And below is the method for undoing the fullscreen.

```
private void closeFullscreenDialog() {
    ((ViewGroup) playerView.getParent()).removeView(playerView);
    ((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_media_frame)).addView(playerView);
    mExoPlayerFullscreen = false;
    mFullScreenDialog.dismiss();
    mFullScreenIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_fullscreen);
}
```

Below is the code snippet for initializing the dialog.

```
mFullScreenDialog = new Dialog(mContext, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen) {
        public void onBackPressed() {
            if (mExoPlayerFullscreen) {
                closeFullscreenDialog();
            }
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    };
```

Comment: FYI this code is very similar to the one in this GitHub project: https://github.com/tiendatit92/ExoplayerFullscreenLandcapse

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible actually. But one workaround I have managed to achieve is changing the width and height of player view to `MATCH_PARENT` when you want to play it in fullscreen (Even in configuration changes).[How to play video full screen in landscape using exoplayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46713761/how-to-play-video-full-screen-in-landscape-using-exoplayer) This could help you.